# Simple GUI application crashes in Qt 5

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

After I downloaded and installed Qt 5. I opened Qt creator 2.6.1 and created a new simple GUI application. But when I try to run it, I get the following error:

> C:\Qt\Qt5.0.0\5.0.0\msvc2010\include\QtCore\qglobal.h:46: error: C1083: Cannot open include file: ‘stddef.h’: No such file or directory

What is the problem and how can I solve it ?

Comment: this file is in VS10 Include Directory. You may need to put this directory in your project Include path.

Comment: Your application doesn't "crash", it doesn't compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this may help (a similar issue discussed here):

http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/10255

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the Windows platform SDK.

By the way: you used the wrong term (I assume). You application didn't crash it refuses to compile.